# Discord.py send message to specific channel

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I would like to send a message in a specific text channel no matter on which server, so I cannot hard-code the ID of my channel.

**This part of the code is working :**

```
    @client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    general = find(lambda x: x.name == 'general',  guild.text_channels)
    if general and general.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages:
        await general.send('Hello {}!'.format(guild.name))
```

**But my problem is this part witch is in a Cog :**

```
import discord, httplib2, random, string
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext.commands import cooldown
from discord.utils import find
class Cog01(commands.Cog):

    def __int__(self, client):
        self.client = client



    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Cog01 is loaded')

        fff = find(lambda x: x.name == 'general',  guild.text_channels)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Cog01(client))
```

I got this error :

```
NameError: name 'guild' is not defined
```

I tried a lot of things, sometimes the error disappeared but it still didn't work.

I am sure it's possible, I lost a older version of my code that worked.

I've been searching for a solution for several hours but the solution might be really simple, I'm new to programming.

Comment: What do you want to happen if your bot is in multiple guilds?

Answer (score 1):

[`commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) has a [`guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.guilds) attribute that returns a list of every guild the client is connected to.
Then every [`Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild) object has a [`system_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.system_channel) attribute. This is on this channel that messages like *User has joined* are sent.

For instance, if you want to send a message on these channels when your bot is ready, you can do it this way:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class Cog01(commands.Cog):
    def __int__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        for guild in self.client.guilds:
            await guild.system_channel.send("I'm ready to go!")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Cog01(client))
```